# How to have a preview component in zend form?

Tags: zend-form

i want to add a preview component to my zend form. This preview component basically allows the user to construct a drop down and see how it looks (yes unfortunately that is a requirement).
so im constructing this dropdown - and when the user clicks on 'add drop down' (a button present in that form) , the drop down has to be previewed on the right-hand side.
could anyone point me in the right direction - do i use iframes/ajax/dojo? I'm not sure how to go about this, and if anyone could give any pointers, i'd really appreciate it. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved this with a simple onLoad javaScript function . there is certainly no way in zend_forms that this can be done - that i'm aware of.